# $\sum_{i=1}^t \phi_i^T(\Lambda_t)^{-1}\phi_i \leq d$ where $\Lambda_t = \lambda I + \sum_{i=1}^{t} \phi_i \phi_i^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I came across the following lemma from a paper I am reading

Let $\Lambda_t = \lambda I + \sum_{i=1}^{t} \phi_i \phi_i^T$ where $\phi_i \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $\lambda > 0 $. Then:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^t \phi_i^T(\Lambda_t)^{-1}\phi_i \leq d
\end{equation}

I know how to prove it (using trace and eigen-value decomposition) but I am trying to understand the inequality in an intuitive manner. I have the following questions:

1. How to explain the inequality in a geometric way
2. As $t$ grows how the summation in the inequality behave
3. As $t$ grows the eigenvalues of $\Lambda_t^{-1}$ decreases. How to use this observation to explain the inequality in "words"?
4. What if in the summation we have $\Lambda_i^{-1}$ instead of $\Lambda_t^{-1}$? ie. what can we say about $\sum_{i=1}^t \phi_i^T(\Lambda_i)^{-1}\phi_i$?

Comment: It might be useful to note that $\sum_{i=1}^{t} \phi_i \phi_i^T$ can be written as $MM^T$, where $M$ is the matrix whose columns are $\phi_1,\dots,\phi_t$.

Comment: Potentially helpful:
$$
\Lambda_t = \lambda I + M_tM_t^T, \\
\sum_{i=1}^t \phi_i^T(\Lambda_t)^{-1}\phi_i = \operatorname{trace}[\sum_{i=1}^t (\Lambda_t)^{-1}\phi_i\phi_i^T] = \operatorname{trace}[(\Lambda_t)^{-1}M_tM_t^T ]
\\ = 
\operatorname{trace}[(\lambda I + M_tM_t^T)^{-1}M_tM_t^T].
$$

Comment: In terms of the [Loewner order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loewner_order), your inequality can be deduced from the fact that
$$
M_tM_t^T \leq M_tM_t^T + \lambda I.
$$